# Google Web Apps send current html page body to email as a pdf

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using Google web app, I have a html form, collecting data, I am trying to send the current pages body as a PDF attached on an email.

code.gs

```
function sendMail(myhtml) {
  
        var blob = Utilities.newBlob(myhtml,MimeType.HTML);

        var options = {'attachments' : 
                       {'fileName' : 'test',
                        'mimeType' : 'application/pdf',
                        'content' : blob.getBytes()
                       }
                      };
        MailApp.sendEmail("myemail address", 'Subject','', options)
      
}
```

HTML page

```
loginForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  console.log("Button Pressed")
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML;
    console.log(body)
 google.script.run.sendMail(body)
```